# Scrollview doesnt work when scrolled on webview on android version lower than 16

Tags: android, android-layout, webview, scrollview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:fbutton="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/progressBarLL"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/app_background_color"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:visibility="visible">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollableContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:scrollbars="none">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="4dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/navigationControlLinearLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:weightSum="4">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/previousPageImageView"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/previous_page_darken" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/dealsPageNumberStatus"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="1/50"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/nextPageImageView"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/next_page_darken" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/dealsFragmentLinearLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_large"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_normal"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_normal"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                android:background="@drawable/background_with_shadow"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="6"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:paddingTop="0dp">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/dealsFragmentImage"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_weight="2"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        android:minHeight="@dimen/min_image_height"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/test_logo" />


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="4.00"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:padding="@dimen/padding_normal">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/dealsFragmentTitle"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:ellipsize="end"
                            android:maxLines="2"
                            android:text="This text is intentionally made larger to go beyound 2 lines"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium"
                            android:padding="@dimen/padding_normal" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/dealsTimeSubmitted"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="0dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:ellipsize="end"
                            android:maxLines="2"
                            android:text="about an hour ago "
                            android:textColor="@color/light_grey"
                            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small"
                            android:padding="@dimen/padding_normal" />

                        <LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="0dp"
                            android:layout_weight="2"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:padding="@dimen/padding_normal">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/dealsCurrentPrice"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:gravity="left|center"
                                android:padding="4dp"
                                android:text="Rs. 135"
                                android:textColor="@color/deals_blue"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_large"
                                android:textStyle="bold" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/dealsOffPercent"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:gravity="left|center"
                                android:padding="4dp"
                                android:text="(90% off)"
                                android:textColor="@color/deals_blue"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium" />

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/dealsOriginalPrice"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:gravity="left|center"
                                android:padding="4dp"
                                android:text="1235698"
                                android:singleLine="true"
                                android:textColor="@color/light_grey"
                                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small" />
                        </LinearLayout>

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="left|center"
                        android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                        android:text="@string/submitted_by"
                        android:textColor="@color/light_text"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/dealsFragmentSubmittedBy"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="left|center"
                        android:text=" aniket007"
                        android:textColor="@color/deals_blue"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:gravity="left|center"
                        android:text=" in "
                        android:textColor="@color/light_text"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/dealsCategory"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:ellipsize="end"
                        android:gravity="left|center"
                        android:maxLines="1"
                        android:paddingRight="4dp"
                        android:text="Mobiles and Mobile Accessories"
                        android:textColor="@color/deals_blue"
                        android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_small" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:background="@color/item_separator"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_normal"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_normal" />


                <WebView
                    android:id="@+id/dealDetail"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/top_deals"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium" />



                <include
                    layout="@layout/list_item_deal_footer"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           />
            </LinearLayout>

            <!--<LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/dealsFragmentCommentLinearLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@color/deals_footer"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="@color/flat_grey" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/dealsFragmentLikeImage"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/comment_icon" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="@color/flat_grey" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/dealsFragmentDislikeImage"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/comment_icon" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="@color/flat_grey" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/dealsFragmentShareImage"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:src="@drawable/popularity_icon" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="1dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:background="@color/flat_grey" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
                android:id="@+id/viewCommentsButton"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:minHeight="@dimen/fb_button_min_height"
                android:text="@string/viewComments"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium"
                fbutton:buttonColor="@color/fbutton_default_color"
                fbutton:cornerRadius="5dp"
                fbutton:shadowColor="@color/fbutton_default_shadow_color"
                fbutton:shadowEnabled="true"
                fbutton:shadowHeight="2dp" />-->

            <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
                android:id="@+id/buyNowButtonPlaceHolder"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:minHeight="@dimen/fb_button_min_height"
                android:text="@string/buy_now"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                fbutton:buttonColor="@color/fbutton_default_color"
                fbutton:cornerRadius="5dp"
                fbutton:shadowColor="@color/fbutton_default_shadow_color"
                fbutton:shadowEnabled="true"
                fbutton:shadowHeight="2dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#ccffffff">

        <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
            android:id="@+id/buyNowButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:minHeight="@dimen/fb_button_min_height"
            android:minWidth="@dimen/buy_now_button_width"
            android:text="@string/buy_now"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/text_size_medium"
            fbutton:buttonColor="@color/fbutton_default_color"
            fbutton:cornerRadius="5dp"
            fbutton:shadowColor="@color/fbutton_default_shadow_color"
            fbutton:shadowEnabled="true"
            fbutton:shadowHeight="2dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am using WebView inside ScrollView and it does work correctly on android versions higher than 16. But on lower version page do not get scrolled when scrolled on webview. Page does get scrolled from right side of page. Links too do not open when clicked on left side but does open from right side.

found few solutions like android:hardwareAccelerated="true", but not working.

Comment: Please show an example of code that did not work and your attempted solution.

Comment: added above. @WilliamDenman

Comment: I am using DrawerLayout in my application and I observed that the area gets covered by drawer is not scrolling. I searched on basis of that also but didn't got working solution. And it happens only with webview. when i created a sample app without Drawer, webview scroll is flawless.